# Error occurred during initialization of VM (java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object)

Tags: windows, eclipse, java, java-7

I'm trying to install Java to use Eclipse (I followed all instructions to install Java and Eclipse) but my Eclipse is not starting due to some bad configuration I guess. I can't figure out why it's not working for me.

**Eclipse Installation:**

1. Extracted Eclipse at `C:\eclipse`
2. Created a shortcut to my desktop having target `C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe`

When I try to run Eclipse with this shortcut, I see following Eclipse splash screen for a second and it disappears. Eclipse does not start at all.

[image: Eclipse Splash Screen]

**JAVA Installation:**

1. Installed JDK at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10`
2. Installed JRE at `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

**Environment Variables Configuration:**

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10
PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;
```

I tested my Java installation using the console and figured out this issue but I don't know how to fix it, and I guess this is causing Eclipse not to start.

**Problem:**

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I was able figure on my end. Thanks for the response! :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to Eclipse folder, locate eclipse.ini file, add following entry (before `-vmargs` if present):

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\javaw.exe
```

Save file and execute eclipse.exe.

Answer (score 10):

please try to execute `java` from

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin

i.e from the location where java is installed.

If it is successful, it means that the error lies somewhere in the classpath.

Also, this guy seems to have had the same problem as yours, [check it out](http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/)

Comment: The solution mentioned in the link was it for me. To summarize, a different version of the JRE got installed in another dir on the PATH. Moving the desired JDK version to the front of the PATH resolved my issue.  Consider exploring this solution if other forces might be able to modify your machine (i.e. other users, automatic updates pushed through by your company, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

Check that downloaded eclipse/JDK/JRE is compatible with your processor/OS architecture that is are they 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Also, review eclipse.ini. You can add the -vm parameter just in case

Comment: @aldrinleal  How to add -vm parameter, please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Not able to run Appium `{“message”:”A new session could not be created. (Original error: ‘java -version’ failed`

I used `Jdk 1.8 and JRE 1.8`, `Classpath` is also set properly but I observed that Java command gives Error to initialization of VM (`java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object)`

```
Solution:
Uninstalled JRE and JDK completely 
Installed JRE 1.8 then
Installed JDK 1.8 
Set Classpath
check Java command works or not and its working 
also able to execute the Appium program thru Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 with JDK1.8 support
```

Comment: This worked for me also. It is easy to test if you have this same issue by giving command "java -version". If it fails, you better reinstall these in this order.

    Note that you need to uninstall separately JDK 8 update.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in my case was when I needed to update jdk 7 to jdk 8, and my bad was just I installed jdk8 and I never installed jre8, only that, the error was solved immediately when I installed jre8.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the desired java directory in PATH before  not needed java directories in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows 7 and I had to install both JDK and JRE and it's a success.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem,Eclipse splash screen for a second and it disappears.Then i noticed due to auto update of java there are two java version installed in my system. when i uninstalled one eclipse started working.

Thanks you..

Answer (score 1):

I've observed this with STS and Eclipse and running java from CMD too on Windows 7/8/10 and following was my simple solution:

Actually, when I installed JDK 8 and STS/Eclipse it created one directory i.e. `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` with the following files:

- C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
- C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
- C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaws.exe

Along with that, it appended Path **Environment variable** of **System** with this location `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

I've just removed above entry from Path **Environment variable** of **System** and added the location of the actual JDK instead i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin`

> Now that is not necessary to add that -vm option in eclipse.ini or
>   SpringToolSuite4.ini either.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent about 1 hour to figure out possible solution for the same error.

So what I did under MS WIndows 7 is following

1. Uninstall all Java packages of all versions.
2. Download last packages  Java SE or JRE  for your 32 or 64 Windows and install it.
3. First install JRE and second is Java SE.

[image]

4. Open text editor and paste this code.

   public class Hello {

   ```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("test");

     }

   }
   ```
5. Save it like Hello.java
6. Go to Console and compile it like

javac Hello.java

7. Execute the code like

java Hello

[image]

Should be no error.

Answer (score 0):

sometime you missed some file like I missed my one file `rt.java`
so better to check yours .........

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 0

   I just spent about 1 hour to figure out possible solution for the
   same error.

   So what I did under MS WIndows 7 is following

   Uninstall all Java packages of all versions.

   Download last packages Java SE or JRE for your 32 or 64 Windows and
   install it.

   First install JRE and second is Java SE.

   1. List item

Answer (score 0):

Below error is thrown when there are multiple versions of jdk on your machine:

error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

so for this Just use below:

set PATH="JDK bin path" in cmd

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issuse, my file location was in `D-drive`, and then i shifted to the `c-Drive` and it works.