# Java program Not running in Eclipse

Tags: java

I installed jdk, jvm and eclipse in my machine and am trying to run a sample java code. It throws me an below error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Comment: That's extremely odd. Can you post the code you're trying to execute?

Comment: Try like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109079/error-occured-during-initialization-of-vm-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java

Comment: Looking around the web, this could be a 32 vs. 64 bits issue. Did you install the correct JDK/JRE for the architecture and OS you're on?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Nothing to do with code here. It's configuration issue.