# Spring-boot Application + Error occurred during initialisation of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I cannot seem to run my Springboot application anymore.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\mnxe\Documents\Web Projects\home.office" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.3.4 clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true spring-boot:run
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What's going on? I hadn't touched the code in about a week. Is it possible that an automatic update to Java is causing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109079/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java?rq=1

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: seems like the error message has nothing got to do with your IDE but rather with your JDK - so see the answers to the post, maybe they can help you.