# Eclipse Neon won't start due to Provisioning exception

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having problems starting the standard Eclipse Neon IDE. I am running Eclipse Neon 1 with Java jdk 1.8.0. After rebooting my computer, Eclipse won't start (no new plugins / software were install during last usage). I tried deleting everything in `.metadata/.plugins/` per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083821/eclipse-does-not-start-when-i-run-the-exe) but it still won't start up. Please help.

P.S. the date of the log seems to be off; I am not sure why but this is the only `!SESSION` in this log file.

Here is a partial copy of the `.metadata/.log` file.

```
!SESSION 2017-06-13 10:46:37.214 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\XXX\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2017-06-13 11:39:01.054

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2017-06-13 11:39:01.054
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/2.10.x/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.fail(CachingRepositoryManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 985 2017-06-15 10:41:43.156
!MESSAGE Remote host closed connection during handshake
!STACK 0
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
.
.
.
```

---

## Update

After opening the CMD with Administrator privilege and running either

```
> java -version
```

or

```
> java
```

both responded with

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

So I guess that something is wrong with my java installation, not eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was with my `java` installation.

First, I try changing the system environment variable `path` to only

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;
```

This failed, resulting in the same java error message. Then I 'reverted' to an older java installation changing both `JAVA_HOME` and `path` to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;
```

This works fine and solves the problem.

---

For reference, these links also helped me.

- [JRE 1.7 returns: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object)
- [Error occurred during initialization of VM (java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109079/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java)
- https://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/

Answer (score 1):

There might be several problems for eclipse to fail on start but in you case this **ProvisionException** occurs may be because of the you didn't cleared proxy or your network connection is set to Ditect it should be Native. And also check SSH certificates

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security

if not found then get it. Please check once you are running eclipse having same architecture means on 32-bit jdk there should be 32-bit eclipse or it won't work.
If you have more than one jre then check eclipse referring to which one. Hope this will help you.